# Changing result table from columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with the following result:

```
Variablename|value|Stringvalue
---------------------------------   
Red            1        'Red'      
Green          8        null     
Purple         8        null     
Violet         3        'Violet'
Blue           2        'Blue'
```

Now i want this to be converted into:

```
Red | Green | Purple | Violet | Blue
--------------------------------------
1       8       8        3        2
'Red'  null    null   'Violet'  'Blue'
```

I've red about Pivot and Unpivot but i can't seem to wrap my head around that

Comment: Is that really how you want the data to come out?  SqlServer will have a fit if you want the columns in one row to be an integer type and be strings in the next row.  Also, why do you want the data this way?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the output in that format, you could do two pivots and union them together. The integer values would have to be converted to a character datatype.  Also, you would need to make sure the correct aggregations are used.  I chose SUM and MAX based on the example, but that may not be what you truly want.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTest (
    VariableName VARCHAR(25)
    ,Value INT
    ,StringValue VARCHAR(25)
    )

INSERT INTO #MyTest
VALUES (
    'Red',1 ,'Red')
    ,('Green',8,NULL)
    ,('Purple',8,NULL)
    ,('Violet',3,'Violet')
    ,('Blue',2,'Blue')

    SELECT CAST([Red] AS VARCHAR(25)) AS Red
    ,CAST([Green] AS VARCHAR(25)) AS Green
    ,CAST([Purple] AS VARCHAR(25)) AS Purple
    ,CAST([Violet] AS VARCHAR(25)) AS Violet
    ,CAST([Blue] AS VARCHAR(25)) AS Blue
FROM (
    SELECT VariableName
        ,Value
    FROM #MyTest
    ) AS a
PIVOT(SUM(Value) FOR VariableName IN (
            [Red]
            ,[Green]
            ,[Purple]
            ,[Violet]
            ,[Blue]
            )) AS pvt

UNION ALL

SELECT [Red]
    ,[Green]
    ,[Purple]
    ,[Violet]
    ,[Blue]
FROM (
    SELECT VariableName
        ,StringValue
    FROM #MyTest
    ) AS a
PIVOT(MAX(StringValue) FOR VariableName IN (
            [Red]
            ,[Green]
            ,[Purple]
            ,[Violet]
            ,[Blue]
            )) AS pvt
```